# Which one among ranking or rankings is to be used for the following sentence?

Tags: usage

"India, China and South Africa have improved their ranking from the previous edition"

or

"India, China and South Africa have improved their rankings from the previous edition"

Which one is correct?

Also please correct the title of this question if it is grammatically incorrect and also this sentence.

Comment: If you were to write:*Peter, Paul and John have bought new cars*, readers would conclude that each had bought a new car. On the other hand, if you wrote that they *had bought a new car", it would sound as though they had combined to buy a single car among them. The same principle applies to your example.

Comment: You might want to wait a few days before accepting an answer.  See: [Not so fast! (When should I accept my answer?)](http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/questions/1307/not-so-fast-when-should-i-accept-my-answer)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

question: which one is better to be used in this sentence: ranking or rankings
(among is used when you are talking about more than 2 things)
I believe that in first sentence they improved one of their rankings, but in second sentence there have to be more that one improvement!!

Comment: So can I use: Which one of ranking or rankings is to be used for the following sentence?

Comment: I think if you add better after is,it will be allright!